# The Empty Set and Identifying It

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to bounce my thoughts off some of you to see if I am on the right page. I want to identify the empty sets.

$\{z: \text {z is a horse and z has 6 legs}\}$

I am tempted to say that this is an empty set because no horse has six legs (hopefully) but almost feel like this is incorrect.

$\{n \in \mathbb{N}: n^2 -n + 41 \text{ is not prime}\}$
I want to say that this is NOT an empty set set because $41^2-41+41$ is prime.

Comment: Correct your final sentence to "*because $41^2-41+41$* **is NOT prime**" so therefore $41$ is in fact an element of the set (*among many others*)

Comment: Looks good to me. I think the key issue with your empty example is that it isn't *entirely inconceivable* that no six-legged horse exists, but don't let that stop you from using that example. It is fine, in spirit.

Comment: I'm sure that in the context of the problem, the set of 6-legged horses was intended as the empty set, from a common knowledge perspective (but of course, although you're sure it's true, you couldn't prove it). One point though -- there is only one empty set, so the better phrasing is "the empty set" rather than "an empty set".

Comment: A less debatable example would be "the set of pigs that can fly".

Comment: @quasi Very good point. That was an oversite on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are correct, if we assume that no horses with $6$ legs exist (as I'm sure there will be pathological examples of horses with $6$ legs).

Comment: I believe the mythical Sleipnir ridden by Odin had 6 legs though...[correction, it had 8]